# Creating Repeated Start and End Dates

Tags: r, date, max, grouping

I have a data set with many variables.  Those of interest are: ID, Episode, Start, End, Assessment Date.  An example data set is shown

```
 ID Episode     Start         End  AssessmentDate
 1       1  1/1/2012  12/21/2012        1/1/2012
 1       1  1/1/2010  12/21/2012      12/12/2012
 1       1  1/1/2010  12/21/2012      12/21/2012
 1       2  1/1/2013           .        1/2/2013
 1       2  1/1/2013           .        2/2/2013
 1       2  1/1/2013           .        3/2/2013
 2       1  1/1/2012           .        4/1/2012
 2       1  1/1/2010           .       5/12/2012
 2       1  1/1/2010           .       6/21/2012
 2       2  1/1/2013           .        7/2/2013
 2       2  1/1/2013           .        8/2/2013
 2       2  1/1/2013           .        9/2/2013
```

I have start dates for everyone, but not any end dates.  I want to identify the end date for each episode and for each patient, for 10,000 patients.  I want the end date to be the last date of assessment per episode number, and I want this to be present for each row between the first and last assessment dates.

I was reading a bit about splitting the data set into many smaller parts based on the ID and Episode, but I feel like there should be a simpler way to do this.  I'm new to R, coming from SAS, and an issue like this in SAS would not give me too much trouble.

I would appreciate any input you may have regarding my data preparations.

Comment: I concur.  You might want to change the example data to something that better represents your actual data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the maximum assessment date by episode using `ddply()` from the `plyr` library:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1, Episode=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), AssessmentDate=as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-12-12", "2012-12-21", "2013-01-02", "2013-02-02", "2013-03-02")))

library(plyr)

df <- ddply(df, .(Episode), transform, End=max(AssessmentDate))
df
```

Which gives you:

```
  ID Episode AssessmentDate        End
1  1       1     2012-01-01 2012-12-21
2  1       1     2012-12-12 2012-12-21
3  1       1     2012-12-21 2012-12-21
4  1       2     2013-01-02 2013-03-02
5  1       2     2013-02-02 2013-03-02
6  1       2     2013-03-02 2013-03-02
```

If you want to do it by patient, you can use `ddply()` with `.(ID)` (assuming that identifies patients) or something like that.

It's also possible to do this with `by()`, but becomes a bit more complicated because it will split the data into lists identified by the values of the grouping variable.

Edit: also, if `Episode` is not unique over the entire data frame, i.e. it repeats for each patient, you could group by both variables, i.e. `ddply(df, .(ID, Episode), ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've properly read in your values as Dates and treated the "." like a `NA` value in R, your sample data frame should have this structure

```
dd<-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Episode = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Start = structure(c(15340, 14610, 14610, 
15706, 15706, 15706), class = "Date"), End = structure(c(15695, 
15695, 15695, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), AssessmentDate = structure(c(15340, 
15686, 15695, 15707, 15738, 15766), class = "Date")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Episode", "Start", "End", "AssessmentDate"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can then calculate the max assessment date per episode using the base `ave()` function with

```
dd$NewEnd <- ave(dd$AssessmentDate, dd$Episode, FUN=max)
```

which gives

```
  ID Episode      Start        End AssessmentDate     NewEnd
1  1       1 2012-01-01 2012-12-21     2012-01-01 2012-12-21
2  1       1 2010-01-01 2012-12-21     2012-12-12 2012-12-21
3  1       1 2010-01-01 2012-12-21     2012-12-21 2012-12-21
4  1       2 2013-01-01       <NA>     2013-01-02 2013-03-02
5  1       2 2013-01-01       <NA>     2013-02-02 2013-03-02
6  1       2 2013-01-01       <NA>     2013-03-02 2013-03-02
```

Here I didn't overwrite the existing End values. I wasn't sure what wanted to do in cases where it didn't match.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table` (data from @MrFlicks post)

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dd)[, NewEnd:=max(AssessmentDate), by=Episode]
 dd
 #      ID Episode      Start        End AssessmentDate     NewEnd
 #1:  1       1 2012-01-01 2012-12-21     2012-01-01 2012-12-21
 #2:  1       1 2010-01-01 2012-12-21     2012-12-12 2012-12-21
 #3:  1       1 2010-01-01 2012-12-21     2012-12-21 2012-12-21
 #4:  1       2 2013-01-01       <NA>     2013-01-02 2013-03-02
 #5:  1       2 2013-01-01       <NA>     2013-02-02 2013-03-02
 #6:  1       2 2013-01-01       <NA>     2013-03-02 2013-03-02
```

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 dd %>% 
    group_by(Episode) %>% 
    mutate(NewEnd=max(AssessmentDate))
```